# How to add spaces between numbers with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

With an input like `123456789`, how can I convert it into a format like `123 456 789` with JavaScript?

`split("").join(" ");` returns `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Comment: not tested, but how about `.split(/(\d{3})/)`?

Comment: You have to start by figuring out what the proper split is: "12 34 56 78 9" is just as valid as "123 456 789" or "1234 5678 9".  Too broad.

Comment: You can use substr `num.substr(0,3)+' '+num.substr(3,3)+' '+num.substr(6,3)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) method:

```
var num = "123456789";
var result = "";
var gap_size = 3; //Desired distance between spaces

while (num.length > 0) // Loop through string
{
    result = result + " " + num.substring(0,gap_size); // Insert space character
    num = num.substring(gap_size);  // Trim String
}

alert(result) // "123 456 789"
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzee145r/)

Answer (score 11):

If you always want the spaces to be by how far from the right you are, use a lookahead which counts in threes

```
'12345678'.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1 '); // "12 345 678"
```

`(?=pattern)` is the lookahead, `\d{3}` is 3 digits, and `(pattern)+` means repeat the last pattern one or more times (greedily) until a the end of the *String* `$`

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex with `split()` like

```js
console.log('123456789'.split(/(\d{3})/).join(' ').trim());
```

Comment: add a trim() at the end

Comment: sorry not correct answer vs: `console.log('1234567891'.split(/(\d{3})/).join(' ').trim());` >> 123  456  789 1

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
var formatted = str.replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ').trim();
```

Comment: Turns `1234` into `123 4`

Answer (score 0):

Try to design a pattern like this.

```js
function numberWithSpaces(value, pattern) {
  var i = 0,
    sequence = value.toString();
  return pattern.replace(/#/g, _ => sequence[i++]);
}

console.log(numberWithSpaces('123456789', '### ### ###'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regex for that

```
var a = "123456789"
a.match(/\d{3}/g).join(" ")
> "123 456 789"
```

The regex matches a group of 3 digits several times